# Django URLs inconsistent, and now returning 404

Tags: django, django-urls

**Previous working configuration of urls.py:**

I'm not using `include`. Previously, a configuration of the project's url.py like this has worked perfectly for me:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^$', 'projectName.appName.views.view1'),
    url(r'^about/$', 'projectName.appName.views.view2'),
    url(r'^contact/$', 'projectName.give.appName.view3'),
    url(r'^contact/thanks/$', 'projectName.appName.views.view4'),
)
```

**Current configuration of urls.py on separate project:**

However, I seem to be facing inconsistent results with this other configuration on another project.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    url(r'^foo/$', 'projectName.appName.views.view1'),
    url(r'^foo/bar1/', 'projectName.appName.views.view2'),
    url(r'^foo/bar2/', 'projectName.appName.views.view3'),
)
```

**What's wrong:**

For example, when I visit the URL at `/foo/bar1`, it inconsitently either brings me to the desired URL or loads up `/foo/` instead while still having `/foo/bar1` displayed in the URL bar in the browser.

`/foo/bar2/` mostly (19 out of 20 times) returns a `404` when that URL is requested. Otherwise it shows `/foo/` but the original URL remains in the browser. It just seems so weird and odd, and this has never happened to me in Django before.

If you noticed the missing `$`'s, I found out through experimentation that this configuration is slightly more reliable. With the `$`'s, all my URLs end up loading `/foo/` while still showing the requested URL in the browser.

I guess that it's worthy to note that `/foo/` and `/foo/bar1/` were mostly working fine (but calling /foo/bar1/ in the browser would still load up `/foo/` instead perhaps 1 out of every 20 times called or so) until I added `/foo/bar2/`.

**How now brown cow:**

I guess this would have to do with regexes, but I'm not sure how should I be handling regexes to make this work, other than to follow what I've done before that was right but now can't work. Yeah so I don't know how does regex work.

If someone could point me in the right direction or tell me where might I have gone wrong that would be very helpful. Thank you!

**Other info:**

I'm developing on Python 2.7, Django 1.3.7 on PythonAnywhere, not locally.

Comment: Er, seems a lot like a code reloading bug. Is it repro locally? Don't know much about PythonAnywhere but, say, modifying the views so you can be sure the code with the correct regex is running should be able to rule out an app server running stale code.

Comment: Well I've got trouble visiting the different URLs so it's kinda hard to test changes, but for what it's worth there's a "Relad App" button here on PA, and I've been mashing that button and refreshing the hell outta my browser and it's just the same problem still.

For static pages, changes made to my html or css code appear to be reflected in the pages I can view.

Comment: And I'm developing on a production server, not locally. Sorry missed out that info up top. I'll add it in.

Comment: Yeah, try making a python-side change (eg, new template var passed from the view) that you can verify from the frontend - having static media and/or templates (stuff read from the filesystem) with app servers still running old code in-memory is a common manifestation of code reloading bugs, so updated html/css/templates doesn't rule it out.

Comment: Gotcha. Just passed a variable from views.py into my template, nothing seems to be wrong there. 

WOAH, I don't know what happened, but it's working totally fine now. Maybe modifying views.py forced the app to reload other files too?

Thanks man that helped, whatever it did :)

Comment: And do I need to answer my own question in this case?

Comment: I'd just close it - if it is bug in their code-reloading, it won't be useful to anyone after it's fixed. If it's something else, we don't really have repro steps anyway...

Comment: uhh. where's the 'close' button..?